# Order values by separate string

Tags: java

Sorry about the non-descriptive title, I couldn't think of a way to explain it better short of 100 words. What I would like to be able to do is sort a list of strings into "boxes" based on a string associated with the main string and an array of strings "order".

For my current setup I am using a HashMap to store the string and it's associated "place-in-the-order" string.

I am aware that my explanation is truly crap so I have made an image which I hope will explain it better:

The variables are initialised as follows:

```
private final String[] order = new String[] {"Severe", "Warning", "Info"};
private final Box[] boxes = new Box[] {new Box(1), new Box(2), new Box(3), new Box(4)};
private final Map<String, String> texts = new HashMap<String, String>();

texts.put("Server on fire!", "Severe");
texts.put("All is good!", "Info");
texts.put("Monkeys detected!", "Warning");
texts.put("Nuke activated!", "Severe");
```

[image: No!]
This shouldn't be too hard to implement but the only way I can think of doing it is by using 3 loops which seems  a bit wasteful and would be slow if there was large numbers of any of the inputs.

Here is some example code which will hopefully show what I have come up with so far and perhaps explain the problem, I have not tested it and don't have an IDE handy so have probably overlooked something.

```
Set<Box> usedBoxes = new HashSet<Box>();

for(String curOrder : order) {
    for (String text : texts) {
        if (texts.get(text).equals(order)) {
            for (Box box : boxes) {
                if (!usedBoxes.contains(box)) {
                    box.setText(text);
                    usedBoxes.add(box);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve, but I feel that there are two things that would make your design much simpler:

1. Don't use Strings for your severity levels. Use enums instead. Enums have a name, may have other fields and methods, and are naturally ordered using their order of definition. And there is no way to make a typo and introduce an unknown severity: they're type-safe

   ```
   enum Severity {
       SEVERE, WARNING, INFO
   }
   ```
2. Don't store things in parallel arrays or associate them with maps. Define a class containing the information of your objects:

   ```
   public class Box {
       private String text;
       private Severity severity;
   }
   ```

Now that you have these, you can simply create a `List<Box>`, and sort it using a `Comparator<Box>` which sorts them by severity, for example:

```
List<Box> boxes = Arrays.asList(new Box("Server is on fire", Severity.SEVERE),
                                new Box("All is good", Severity.INFO),
                                ...);
Collections.sort(boxes, new Comparator<Box>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Box b1, Box b2) {
        return b1.getSeverity().compareTo(b2.getSeverity());
    }
}
```

or even simpler, with Java 8:

```
boxes.sort(Comparator.comparing(Box::getSeverity));
```

Comment: The reason for using severity as a string is that I want it to be customisable for the end user.

Comment: Then make it a class implementing Comparable<Severity>, with a name and a rank property (the rank being the way to compare a severity to another one).

Answer (score 1):

You should make your "statuses" (Severe, Info etc) into an Enum.

```
public enum StatusLevel {
    Severe,
    Warning,
    Info;
}
```

You can then sort by `StatusLevel` natively as long as you define the in a top to bottom order.

If you want to supply your `Box` object directly insead of pulling out the `StatusLevel` or have a secondary sort by another property like time or alphabetically you should implement your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Also you may want to look into [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) or other Map that keeps its order so you don't have to resort a `HashMap` every time as it does not guarantee order.